# Rotate all child elements but still fit to parent element

Tags: css, flexbox, css-transforms, css-grid

A picture is needed here.

[image]

I have a 9 grid defined using CSS grid like this...

```
.App {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "1 2 3" "4 5 6" "7 8 9";
}
```

In the 2, 4, 6 and 8 `grid-areas` I've got a number of input elements. They stretch to fit their parent element using flexbox like this ...

```
.ItemsSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ItemsSection * {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

You can see from the image that I've tried to rotate the 4 `grid-area`. It didn't work. I'm not surprised about that but I'm struggling to think how I would achieve that layout without a lot of pain.

What I need is for the inputs to be transformed by 90 degrees and **then** fitted to the parent element so that they are sideways on but sized to the mid-blue area.

Honestly, I'm not even sure what to google for that!

I'm really looking for a CSS only solution but beggars can't be choosers.

**EDIT:** Code snippet added as requested

```css
 .app {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: "a b c" "d e f" "g h i";
    }

    .ItemSection {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding:10px;
    }

    .ItemSection * {
        flex: 1;
        font-size: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .one {
        background-color: #999;
        grid-area: a;
    }

    .two {
        background-color: #666;
        grid-area: b;
    }

    .three {
        background-color: #999;
        grid-area: c;
    }

    .four {
        background-color: #666;
        grid-area: d;
    }

    .five {
        background-color: #999;
        grid-area: e;
    }

    .six {
        background-color: #666;
        grid-area: f;
    }

    .seven {
        background-color: #999;
        grid-area: g;
    }

    .eight {
        background-color: #666;
        grid-area: h;
    }

    .nine {
        background-color: #999;
        grid-area: i;
    }
```

```html
<div class="app">
        <div class="ItemSection one">
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
        </div>
        <div class="ItemSection two">
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
        </div>
        <div class="ItemSection three">
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
        </div>
        <div class="ItemSection four">
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
        </div>
        <div class="ItemSection five">
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
        </div>
        <div class="ItemSection six">
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
        </div>
        <div class="ItemSection seven">
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
        </div>
        <div class="ItemSection eight">
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
        </div>
        <div class="ItemSection nine">
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
            <input />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know this isn't possible due to the fact a transform, like a rotation, doesn't trigger a reflow, so you can't rely on that to get the result you want… unless you can use values like `width: 33vh` and `height: 33vw`? A JavaScript solution seems more likely to work, if you put a `div` inside the grid `item`, and simply use the logic of `div.width = item.height` and `div.height = parent.width`. Is a CSS-only solution exists, I'd love to hear about it!

Comment: When you `transform` an element, it is only visually transformed, technically it behaves and is treated as if nothing changed.

Comment: Furthermore, for us to be able to suggest a proper solution, we'll need a working code snippet.

Comment: I came up with this as a proof of concept: https://codepen.io/chriskirknielsen/pen/mXWwdO - maybe it'll help you get on the right track?

Comment: @LGSon done. I was on the train when I posted and a bit limited on time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite my comment to your question with a [working solution](https://codepen.io/chriskirknielsen/pen/mXWwdO) (albeit it'll only work in a certain layout), I believe you can solve your issue with `writing-mode: sideways-lr;` (and maybe prefixes?) but you might want to tweak how your `input`s are sized.

```css
.app {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "a b c" "d e f" "g h i";
}

.ItemSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
}

.ItemSection * {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.one {
  grid-area: a;
}

.two {
  grid-area: b;
}

.three {
  grid-area: c;
}

.four {
  grid-area: d;
}

.five {
  grid-area: e;
}

.six {
  grid-area: f;
}

.seven {
  grid-area: g;
}

.eight {
  grid-area: h;
}

.nine {
  grid-area: i;
}

.one,
.three,
.five,
.seven,
.nine {
  background-color: #999;
}

.two,
.four,
.six,
.eight {
  background-color: #666;
  -webkit-writing-mode: sideways-lr;
  -ms-writing-mode: sideways-lr;
      writing-mode: sideways-lr;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="ItemSection one">
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
  </div>
  <div class="ItemSection two">
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
  </div>
  <div class="ItemSection three">
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
  </div>
  <div class="ItemSection four">
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
  </div>
  <div class="ItemSection five">
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
  </div>
  <div class="ItemSection six">
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
  </div>
  <div class="ItemSection seven">
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
  </div>
  <div class="ItemSection eight">
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
  </div>
  <div class="ItemSection nine">
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
  </div>
</div>
```